# Specific range within a list (python)

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a list of integers which I have extracted from a string of text, so when I print the list (which I have called `test`) I get:

```
['135', '2256', '1984', '3985', '1991', '1023', '1999']
```

and I want to print or make a new list containing only numbers within a certain range, e.g. between 1000-2000. I tried the following, but it still returns all of the items in my original list.

```
for i in test:
    if i>1000:
        print i
    elif i<2000:
        print i
```

And I can't work out why it would still be printing numbers below 1000 or above 2000.

Comment: don't compare strings with integers...

Comment: hint #2: 1 is less than 2000, 1000 is more than 1000

Comment: btw `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()` in python 3, isn't this python 2?

Comment: of course it is python 2: the print statements!!!

Comment: Sorry yes, it is python 2 apologies. Also I didn't notice that it was a list of strings instead of integers - problem solved!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First convert your list of strings to a list of ints:

```
ints_list = [int(x) for x in test]
```

Then you can filter this list however you would like. We can do this with a list comprehension like the above line. Notice the `and` that makes it so that the number has to meet both conditions to be in the list.

```
filtered_list = [x for x in ints_list if x > 1000 and x < 2000]
```

Comment: I believe you mean `x < 2000`

Comment: Thanks @NinadGaikwad

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't realise I had strings instead of integers, that makes sense. However when I try to run the first line in your comment I get an error: 
" TypeError: 'str' object is not callable". Do you maybe know what the cause could be? Thanks again!

Comment: You don't have a variable named str do you? That might cause that since that is supposed to be reserved as a Python keyword.

Comment: Try this: `[int(x) for x in ['135', '2256', '1984', '3985', '1991', '1023', '1999']]`

Tested in Python 3.6 and Python 2.7

Comment: I must have done, I closed the terminal and reopened it and now your solution works - thanks for your help

Comment: Awesome, I wondered if it was maybe some unexpected behavior due to forgetting what happened in the terminal session. Happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by stating that this just *cannot* run under python 3 because you cannot compare strings (as contained in your list) to integers anymore without error.

On python 2, all `i>1000` tests succeed.

```
>>> "12">1000
True
```

Fortunately this has been fixed in python 3 and it avoids those mistakes:

```
>>> "12">1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 301, in runcode
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()
```

I suggest to test integers (if you want to keep your list elements as strings, else convert beforehand):

```
lst = ['135', '2256', '1984', '3985', '1991', '1023', '1999']

print([x for x in lst if 1000<int(x)<2000])
```

or convert to integer first, then filter:

```
lst = [int(x) for x in lst]
print([x for x in lst if 1000<x<2000])
```

using *chained comparisons* which are very readable in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's ambiguous whether you are using Python 2 or 3. You tagged Python 3, but in this case you should be getting a `TypeError` instead of semantically incorrect output. This answer works for both versions of Python.

`test` is a list of strings, but you want to do integer comparisons.

Build a list of integers first, then apply your algorithm.

```
>>> test = ['135', '2256', '1984', '3985', '1991', '1023', '1999']
>>> test_ints = [int(x) for x in test] # or test_ints = map(int, test)
>>> for i in test_ints:
...     if i > 1000:
...         print(i)
...     elif i < 2000:
...         print(i)
... 
135
2256
1984
3985
1991
1023
1999
```

Now the code runs, but still has bugs. Note how `135` is falsely printed, because it is not greater than `1000` but smaller than `2000`.

A bug free version could look like this:

```
>>> for i in test_ints:
...     if 1000 < i < 2000:
...         print(i)
... 
1984
1991
1023
1999
```

... and if you want to build a list instead of just printing the filtered elements, create an empty list and `append` the hits.

```
>>> result = []
>>> for i in test_ints:
...     if 1000 < i < 2000:
...         result.append(i)
... 
>>> result
[1984, 1991, 1023, 1999]
```

If you are already comfortable with list comprehensions, the shorter version to write this looks like this:

```
>>> result = [i for i in test_ints if 1000 < i < 2000]
>>> result
[1984, 1991, 1023, 1999]
```

Alternatively, the conversion to `int` could be done on the fly by mapping the `int` builtin onto your original list `test` inside a single comprehension.

```
>>> result = [i for i in map(int, test) if 1000 < i < 2000]
>>> result
[1984, 1991, 1023, 1999]
```

Personally, I prefer the last solution for its brevity.

Comment: (Memory optimization: you could use a generator expression for the conversion or, in the case of Python 2, `itertools.imap` over `map`, but these details stroke me as out of scope for OP's current understanding.)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are comparing a `string` with an `integer` and if the number is not more than `1000` for example the first value: `135`, if move to the `elif` in which `135` < `2000`.

What you can try is:

```
for i in test:
    if 1000 < int(i) < 2000:
        print i
```

That is given that all your values are integer values.

Comment: yes, that works, but real explanation is that OP is comparing strings with integers in python 2.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
>>> l = ['135', '2256', '1984', '3985', '1991', '1023', '1999']

>>> for i in l:
     if (int(i) > 1000) and (int(i) <  2000):
         print i
```

- converting first str to int and then comparing your condition

Answer (score 0):

You are currently facing two problems: your numbers are not really `integers`, but `strings`, and the `if` condition isn't working as you expect.

Starting with the `integer` problem, you can see that you're handling `strings` which represents a number by printing their type at the start of the `for` loop:

```
for i in test:
    print type(i) # string!
```

in python is pretty easy to convert `strings` into `integers`:

```
i = int(i) # now 'i' is an integer
```

In  this chunk of code, python will try to convert the string into an integer, and if he can't (i.e. `int("Hello World!")`), it raises an error.

The second problem is in the logic behind your `if` condition, but fortunately Python is really similar to english, so we can easily translate our code into spoken language:

> for each number in my list,
>   if the number is higher than 1000, print the number
>   else if the number is lower than 2000, print the number

So now we can simulate some cases:

> our number is 1337
>   is the number higher than 1000? YES! so - print the number

or

> our number is 42
>   is the number higher than 1000? NO! go on
>   is the number lower than 2000? YES! print the number

and at last:

> our number is 2048
>   is the number higher than 1000? YES! print the number

so now the problem seems clear.
the `english sentence` that you want to transform into code is:

> for each number in my list,
>   if the number is higher than 1000 **and** the number is lower than 2000, print the number

I am not going to write you the code, but in other answers you can find it

Comment: problem is that OP is comparing strings with integers in python 2.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre didn't noticed - thanks, fixing it right now