# How to define a range and using an input, use that range to print

Tags: range

i would like to write code that will print out a selected message if the input falls within a pre-defined range from 1 to 10. im very new to this so my code may not even be right to begin with.

here is the code.

```
a = range (1, 3)
b = range (4, 6)
c = range (7, 9)
d = 10
scale = int(input())
if scale == a:
    print ("I'm sure things will get better!")

if scale == b:
   print ("Thats not too bad!")

if scale == c:
   print ("Keep up the good work!")
```

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question, programming language?

Comment: Sorry, its python 3.9

Comment: Take a look a this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778594/specific-range-within-a-list-python

Comment: It works using the less than more than signs. so it is not possible to define a variable as my original code?

```
scale = int(input())
if scale > 1 <= 3:
    print ("I'm sure things will get better!")

if scale > 3 <= 6:
   print ("Thats not too bad!")

if scale > 6 <= 9:
   print ("Keep up the good work!")
```
@FrancoisTaljaard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if scale in range(1, 3):
   print ("I'm sure things will get better!")
if scale in range(4, 6):
   print ("Thats not too bad!")
if scale in range(7, 9):
   print ("Keep up the good work!")
```

maybe like this, not sure if you need the range in a variable, but this way you dont have to declare the variable.